# How to sort command-line arguments in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, iterator, arguments

All I want to do for right now is sort command-line arguments, but I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error, which I think means I have a pointer pointing at an imaginary place.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  vector<int> the_args;
  vector<int>::iterator it;
  it = the_args.begin(); //this seems logical to me.
  int i = 1; //so I'll skip over argv[0]

  while (i < argc) 
  {
    the_args.insert (it, atoi(argv[i]));
    i++;
    it++;//this is probably the perpetrator.
  }

  sort (the_args.begin(), the_args.end());

  for (it = the_args.begin(); it < the_args.end(); it++) //or else it's this
  {
    cout << *it << " ";
  }


  return 0;
}
```

I eventually want to program games. I've got enough experience in Java that I figured I could start trying to screw around in C++ and figure it out... but maybe not?  Please be nice in your answers, I'm really discouraged that I even have to ask a question on here about sorting something.

Comment: just use `push_back`, `insert` is invalidating `it`.

Comment: just use `Boost.Program_options` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/program_options.html and do yourself a favor .

Comment: Knowing some Java and "trying to screw around" is going to be a slow and error-filled way to learn C++. Can I suggest a good book instead? [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/445976)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
vector<string> the_args( argv + 1, argv + argc );
```

Or:

```
vector<int> the_args;
for( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) 
{
    the_args.push_back( atoi( argv[i] ) );
}
```

Then just sort it with `std::sort` as you’re doing.

Comment: @quantdev: `to_string` and `atoi` go opposite ways. `strtol` is good if one wants error checking.

Answer (score 3):

```
the_args.insert (it, atoi(argv[i]));
```

This invalidates `it`. Scrap the iterator, and just use `push_back`.

```
the_args.push_back(atoi(argv[i]));
```

Alternatively, `insert` returns a valid iterator to the object that was just inserted, so you could also do this:

```
it = the_args.insert (it, atoi(argv[i]));
```

But that's unnecessarily complicated if you are just inserting at the end of the vector. Here's an option which replaces your entire loop, if you're a fan of one-liners:

```
std::transform(argv + 1, argv + argc, std::back_inserter(the_args), std::atoi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  vector<int> the_args
  if ( argc > 1 ) the_args.reserve( argc - 1 );

  for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) the_args.push_back( std::atoi( argv[i] ) );

  std::sort( the_args.begin(), the_args.end() );

  for ( int x : the_args )
  {
    std::cout << x << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```